# Why does my while loop not work with these functions?

Tags: python, pynput

When I have this while loop by itself, it works, but with the functions, it stops working. I have tested the functions to make sure that they are working properly, and they are, but even though `autoclicker == 1` it won't do the while loop.

```
autoclicker = 0

def on_release(key):
    global autoclicker

    if key == keyboard.Key.f6:
        autoclicker += 1
        print(autoclicker)

def on_press(key):
    global autoclicker

    if autoclicker == 1 and key == keyboard.Key.f6:
        autoclicker -= 1
        print(autoclicker)
        sys.exit()

with keyboard.Listener(
        on_release=on_release,
        on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

while autoclicker == 1:
    mouse.press(Button.left)
    print(f"Left mouse button pressed.")

    mouse.release(Button.left)
    print(f"Left mouse button released.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `while` loop inside the listener like so:

```
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_release=on_release,
        on_press=on_press) as listener:
    

    while autoclicker == 1:
        mouse.press(Button.left)
        print(f"Left mouse button pressed.")

        mouse.release(Button.left)
        print(f"Left mouse button released.")

    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your code.

1. If you don't want to the thread block your code.(You said that your code in the end wouldn't run.).Change:

```
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_release=on_release,
        on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

to

```
listener = keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release, on_press=on_press)
listener.start()
```

2. I am not sure why you use `while autoclicker == 1` because you define `autoclicker = 0` at the beginning,your while loop won't make sense.You may need some changes in your code.

Comment: I did ```while autoclicker == 1``` because the function is supposed to add one if F6 is pressed. I want F6 to be the start and end key.

Comment: @Nipar `While True` and `if autoclicker==1:break`, the logic of the code you post is invalided.